# How to preload videos in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to preload videos in flutter without loading every single time using page view like tiktok and reels. There shouldn't be any loading when scrolling between videos. If and else state management is used only provider or Riverpod needs to be used. Below code works perfectly but there is a loading in between each video scroll.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> urls = [
      'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gyft-app-official.appspot.com/o/publicData%2FhomePage%2FscrapBook%2Fa4%2F30.%20Anil%20Kumar.mp4?alt=media&token=57afa0dc-7514-4932-828b-1fb014178eeb',
      'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gyft-app-official.appspot.com/o/publicData%2FhomePage%2FscrapBook%2Fa4%2F39.%20Vaishnavi%20Chaitanya.mp4?alt=media&token=532171ee-ab13-4292-aabf-c9cd2144eace'
    ];

    return PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: urls.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Video(urls[index]);
        });
  }
}

class Video extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  const Video(this.url, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  VideoState createState() => VideoState();
}

class VideoState extends State<Video> {
  late CachedVideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = CachedVideoPlayerController.network(widget.url)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        _controller.play();
        _controller.setLooping(true);
        setState(() {});
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _controller.value.isInitialized
        ? GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            },
            child: CachedVideoPlayer(_controller),
          )
        : Container();
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    _controller.pause();
    debugPrint('Paused');
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    debugPrint('Disposed');
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

https://miro.medium.com/max/1050/1*wrTi9S-tuFFfEplVGbnj6A.gif

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used in my app, [preload_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/preload_page_view), it preloads a specific count of pre/next pages:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new PreloadPageView.builder(
      itemCount: ...,
      itemBuilder: ...,
      onPageChanged: (int position) {...},
      .....
      preloadPagesCount: 3,
      controller: PreloadPageController(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I tried PreLoadPageView but It is playing all the videos at the same time.
Also it is not disposing the video controller of the previous page while scrolling to the next page.
Could you please help me out with this.

Comment: You have to create new controller for every video and it should be dispose onPageChange.

Comment: How to create new controller for every video? How can we access video controllers outside the class

Comment: You have to make one StatefulWidget which will get URL every time and return to you Video Player widget. That widget will maintain controller.

Comment: `PreloadPageView` doesn't work